# Casting in Objective-C does not work as expected

Tags: objective-c, casting, nsmutablearray

I am new to programming with Objective-C and Stackoverflow, and I need some help.

I'm trying to get an object from a NSMutableArray and check one of its internal properties. I figured the best way to do this is by doing the following cast:

```
GenericRoom *room = (GenericRoom*)[myRooms objectAtIndex: currentIndex + side];

if (room.myType == EMPTY) {
    return YES;
}
```

The problem is that when I create a class of type GenericRoom, your constructor already defines myType as EMPTY. When I insert the instances in NSMutrableArray, I changed to myType TAVERN this way:

```
NSMutableArray *myRooms = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:15];

for (int i = 0: i <15: i + +) {
    GenericRoom tmpRoom * = [[GenericRoom alloc] initWithType: TAVERN];
    myRooms insertObject: tmpRoom atIndex i];
}
```

But when I do the cast that quote up there, it simply creates a new instance of the object GenericRoom, instead of copying the object inside NSMutableArray, making its result is always YES, my failing vereficação.

Is there any better way to solve this problem?
Thank you all.

EDIT: The complete code

GenericRoom.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

enum Rooms {
    EMPTY, TAVERN, WARRIORGUILD, MAGEGUILD
}roomsType;

@interface GenericRoom : CCLayer {
    CCSprite *mySprite;
    enum Rooms myType;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSprite *mySprite;
@property enum Rooms myType;
@property int test;

- (id)initWithSprite: (NSString *)file;
- (id)initWithType: (enum Rooms)roomType;

@end
```

GenericRoom.m

```
#import "GenericRoom.h"
@implementation GenericRoom
@synthesize mySprite, myType, test;

-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithType: (enum Rooms) roomType {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        myType = roomType;

    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithSprite: (NSString *)file {

    if (self = [super init]) {
        mySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:file];

        [self addChild: mySprite];
    }

    return self;
}
@end
```

RoomManager.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "GenericRoom.h"
#import "RoomTavern.h"
#import "RoomEmpty.h"

enum Sides {
    LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN
}theSides;

@interface RoomManager : CCLayer {
    CGSize size;
    NSMutableArray *myRooms;
}

- (void) CreateRoom: (enum Rooms)roomType;


@end
```

RoomManager.m

```
@implementation RoomManager

-(id)init {

    if (self = [super init]) {
        size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        myRooms = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:15];

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            GenericRoom *tmpRoom = [[GenericRoom alloc] initWithType:TAVERN];
            tmpRoom.test = 10;
            [myRooms insertObject:tmpRoom atIndex:i];
        }

        [self CreateRoom:TAVERN];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) CreateRoom: (enum Rooms)roomType {
    switch (roomType) {
        case TAVERN:
        {
            //Create the Tavern Main Room
            RoomTavern *tmpRoom = [[RoomTavern alloc] initWithSprite:@"room-hd.png"];
            tmpRoom.mySprite.position = ccp(size.width/2,size.height/2);

            [self addChild:tmpRoom];

            [myRooms removeObjectAtIndex:8];
            [myRooms insertObject:tmpRoom atIndex:8];

            if ([self CheckAdjacentRooms:8 andSide:LEFT]) {
                RoomEmpty *tmpEmptyRoom = [[RoomEmpty alloc] initWithSprite:@"roomToBuild-hd.png"];
                tmpEmptyRoom.mySprite.position = ccp(tmpRoom.mySprite.position.x - tmpRoom.mySprite.contentSize.width, tmpRoom.mySprite.position.y);

                [self addChild:tmpEmptyRoom];

                [myRooms insertObject:tmpEmptyRoom atIndex:7];
            }

            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (BOOL) CheckAdjacentRooms: (int)currentIndex andSide:(enum Sides)side {
    int leftRightSide = 0;
    if(side == LEFT)
        leftRightSide = -1;
    else if (side == RIGHT) 
        leftRightSide = 1;

    GenericRoom *roomTmp  = (GenericRoom *)[myRooms objectAtIndex:currentIndex + side];

    if (roomTmp.myType == EMPTY) {
        return YES;
    }
    else
        return NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: Casting doesn't create a new object. Something else is wrong.

Comment: Your code looks OK (other than the memory leak if you're not using ARC).  I cannot see why that fails.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <15; i++) {`

Comment: Where are these two blocks of code in relation to each other?  Same function? same class/different methods?

Comment: What does `initWithType:` look like?  You can check the contents of your array using `NSLog(@"myRooms: %@", myRooms);` at the point where you get a room from it.

Comment: Also, `GenericRoom room *= ...` isn't going to compile.

Comment: @trojanfoe yes, i'm using ARC...

Comment: @DanF yes, it is in same class/different methods

Comment: @PhillipMills 
-(id)initWithType: (enum Rooms) roomType {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        myType = roomType;
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: Check that `room != nil` as if `EMPTY == 0` then that will also cause that test to return `YES`

Comment: @trojanfoe in fact, EMPTY is an enum ... This test verifies in the future other types of enums therefore not fit to test if the object is nil;

Comment: How is `myRooms` getting from one method to another?

Comment: @DanF it's a property of the object

Comment: @LuizThiagodeSouza: EMPTY is part of an enum, but it is the zero value of that enum, so it would be the value returned by nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enhance @Dan F answer. Read this ...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW7

... what's `nil` messaging. Your locally declared `myRooms` variable hides your `myRooms` property (= instance variable). In other words, `myRooms` is `nil`. And what happens ...

```
GenericRoom *room = (GenericRoom*)[myRooms objectAtIndex: currentIndex + side];
```

Because of `nil` messaging rules, `[myRooms objectAtIndex:...]` returns `nil`, thus your `room` is set to `nil`.

```
if (room.myType == EMPTY) {
    return YES;
}
```

And `room.myType` sends message `myType` to `room` object. And because `room` is `nil`, return value is `0` - enums does contain integer scalar values - this is the reason why it returns `0`. And I assume that `EMPTY` is first element in your enum = has value `0`. And `0` == `0` => returns `YES` even when your `myRooms` instance variable is `nil`.

Comment: This is just enhancement to @Dan F answer. I assume he is right. Do what he proposed and if it will not work, post the whole code of your `GenericRoom` class (both .h, .m) and also the whole class where you do work with `GenericRoom` class. It's hard to guess when you did not provide full code.

Answer (score 0):

If your code above is how it appears in your actual project, then the problem is you are re-declaring your `myRooms` object.  When you write this line:

```
NSMutableArray *myRooms = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:15];
```

you are creating a new locally-scoped object named `myRooms` that is lost when you exit the current scope (method, block, etc.)

What you need to do to fix this is simply remove the `NSMutableArray *` at the beginning of the line, and it will assign the newly allocated array to your property.  Like so:

```
myRooms = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:15];
```

Comment: Sorry, thats is what i do... I just write NSMutableArray *myRooms = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:15]; to illustrate the myRooms creation...

In the real code, the NSMutableArray *myRooms = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:15] is declared in the init method, and the for in another method

Comment: If you are still using `NSMutableArray *myRooms = [[NSMutableArray....` you are still wrong, regardless of what function it is in.  If it is declared as a property, you do NOT need to have `NSMutableArray *` in front of the initialization line

Comment: Ok, the code you originally posted had me confused, I'll take another look and see if I can figure out whats wrong

Comment: When i breakpoint the "FOR" in the RooManager.m's init function, the myRooms NSMutableArray cannot identify the GenericRoom class =/

Comment: What do you mean by cannot identify the class?

Comment: Sorry for taking up your time ... I found out what the error is. In (GenericRoom *) [myRooms objectAtIndex: currentIndex + side], the expression "side currentIndex +" returns a wrong value. When I just changed it to "7", it worked ...

Answer (score 0):

Your initialiser seems to have some flaws, that might cause your issues.

```
// NOTE: `Rooms` instead of `enum Rooms`
- (id)initWithType:(Rooms)roomType 
{ 
   if (self = [super init])  
   {
      // NOTE: accessor is used, otherwise the value is cleared when out of scope
      self.myType = roomType; 
   }
   return self;
}
```

Comment: __// NOTE: accessor is used, otherwise the value is cleared when out of scope__ invalid statement. You can use `_myType = roomType` and nothing is cleared when you're out of scope if `_myType` is ivar for `myType` property.